# Pentaho report designer grouping in subreport

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm working in Pentaho Report Designer and my question is how can i use group variable [Group variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lr5U.png) in my subreports? For example i have group by date and want to filter data in my subreport [subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZqC.png) by date. Because grouping by date is not working in subreport and i want to filter data by current group value.

I tried to call $(groupdate), [groupdate], setting variable name as groupdate and nothing works.